# VirtualBox: How to capture shortcuts in the guest OS?

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, keyboard, wayland

I've set up a VM with VirtualBox.

The problem is that the **guest system doesn't capture all keys**. Although, the option **Auto Capture Keyboard** is set. Keys like <kbd>Super</kbd> or shortcuts like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> are always handled by the host system and not by the guest as I would expect.

How can I capture all keys (except the Host Key) within the guest system?

---

Host: *Linux arch 4.11.3-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun May 28 10:40:17 CEST 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux*

Guest: *Linux kali 4.9.0-kali4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.25-1kali1 (2017-05-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux*

Comment: What window manager are you running on the host?

Comment: *XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME* and *GDMSESSION=gnome*

Comment: I guess the host system is using Wayland.

Comment: yes, it is: *XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the *XDG_SESSION_TYPE* from *wayland* to *x11* solved the problem.
The following line in the `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` file has to be uncommented:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

Comment: That is one way to do it, but what if I still want to use wayland? Boxes seem to work fine.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution?